# Circular Progress Bar with custom text in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, progress-bar

I need to Create a Circular Progress Bar Like below.

[image]

I have tried [CircleView Progress bar plugin](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2182)

But it Does not allow  to Inner Custom text like my image. Please Help me to solve this problem.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Did you tried `setText()` method in `CircleProgressView`? You also have to set `TextMode` to `TextMode.TEXT` to see the text.

Comment: I have tried it. But there we can show single line of text. not multiline text with Style like above

Comment: try this. it is easy customizable. https://github.com/natasam/DemoProgressViewsLibApp

Answer (score 8):

This is one of mine that I've made. It has mostly everything you're after, and I'm sure you'll be able to fix it up to look exactly how you want. It's MIT licensed, so you can do almost anything you want with it, just keep the copyright notice.

Copyright notice

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2015 Tom Wijgers
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software
 * and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction,
 * including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute,
 * sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software
 * is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * Except as contained in this notice, the name(s) of the above copyright holders shall not be used
 * in advertising or otherwise to promote the sale, use or other dealings in this Software without
 * prior written authorization.
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or
 * substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED,
 * INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A
 * PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR
 * COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER
 * IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
 * CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */
```

ProgressBarRoundedRing.java

```
package com.sss.utilities.widgets;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.SweepGradient;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.ColorInt;
import android.support.annotation.ColorRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.Layout.Alignment;
import android.text.StaticLayout;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.sss.utilities.AppCompatUtils;
import com.sss.utilities.R;
import com.sss.utilities.TypefaceManager;

/**
 * A circular progress bar, with rounded caps, and a gradient
 *
 * @author Tom Wijgers
 */

public class ProgressBarRoundedRing extends ProgressBar
{
    private static int sCount;
    private static final String TAG = ProgressBarRoundedRing.class.getName();
    @SuppressWarnings({"FieldCanBeLocal", "unused"})
    private String iTAG;
    private int iCount;

    private int iStartColor = Color.WHITE;
    private int iEndColor = Color.BLACK;
    private int iBackgroundColour = Color.TRANSPARENT;
    private int iTextColor = Color.WHITE;

    private boolean iShowProgress = false;
    private boolean iShowPercentage = false;
    private String iText = null;
    private String iAdditionalText = null;
    private String iTextTypeface = null;
    //private int iFontStyle = Typeface.NORMAL;

    private long iStart = -1;

    private Typeface mTypeface = null;

    private Paint mPaint;
    private SweepGradient mGradient;
    private TextPaint mTextPaint;
    private StaticLayout mTextLayout;
    private StaticLayout mAddTextLayout;

    private boolean resized = true;
    private int oldWidth;
    private int width;
    private float stroke;

    // Members for performance reasons.
    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    private int period;
    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    private float startAngle;
    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    private float size;
    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    private float sweepAngle;
    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    private float angle;

    public ProgressBarRoundedRing(@NonNull Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ProgressBarRoundedRing(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        init(context, attrs, 0, 0);
    }

    private void init(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        iCount = sCount++;
        iTAG = TAG + "$" + iCount;
        TypefaceManager.init(context);
        loadAttrs(attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        initPaints();
    }

    private void loadAttrs(@Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        if (attrs == null)
            return;

        TypedArray a = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.ProgressBarRoundedRing,
                defStyleAttr,
                defStyleRes
        );

        TypedArray ta = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.Typeface,
                defStyleAttr,
                defStyleRes
        );

        try
        {
            iStartColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ProgressBarRoundedRing_colorStart, iStartColor);
            iEndColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ProgressBarRoundedRing_colorEnd, iEndColor);
            iBackgroundColour = a.getColor(R.styleable.ProgressBarRoundedRing_colorBackground, iBackgroundColour);
            iTextColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ProgressBarRoundedRing_colorText, iTextColor);
            iShowProgress = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ProgressBarRoundedRing_showProgress, iShowProgress);
            iShowPercentage = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ProgressBarRoundedRing_showProgressAsPercentage, iShowPercentage);
            iAdditionalText = a.getString(R.styleable.ProgressBarRoundedRing_additionalText);
            iTextTypeface = ta.getString(R.styleable.Typeface_fontAssetName);
        }
        finally
        {
            a.recycle();
            ta.recycle();
        }
    }

    private void initPaints()
    {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
        mTextPaint.setColor(iTextColor);
        mTextPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        if(mTypeface == null && iTextTypeface != null)
            mTypeface = TypefaceManager.getTypeface(iTextTypeface);

        if(mTypeface != null)
            mTextPaint.setTypeface(mTypeface);
    }

    public ProgressBarRoundedRing(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ProgressBarRoundedRing(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return iCount;
    }

    /**
     * @param color the starting colour of the gradient
     */
    public void setStartColor(@ColorInt int color)
    {
        iStartColor = color;

        updateGradient();
    }

    private void updateGradient()
    {
        if (isIndeterminate())
        {
            int[] colours = {iStartColor, iEndColor, iStartColor, iEndColor, iStartColor};
            float[] position = {0f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 0.75f, 1f};

            mGradient = new SweepGradient(width / 2, width / 2, colours, position);
        }
        else
        {
            int[] colours = {iStartColor, iStartColor, iEndColor, iStartColor};
            float[] position = {0f, 0.01f, 0.01f, 1f};

            mGradient = new SweepGradient(width / 2, width / 2, colours, position);
        }

        postInvalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @param color the starting colour of the gradient
     */
    public void setStartColorResource(@ColorRes int color)
    {
        iStartColor = AppCompatUtils.getColor(getResources(), color);

        updateGradient();
    }

    /**
     * @param color the ending colour of the gradient
     */
    public void setEndColor(@ColorInt int color)
    {
        iEndColor = color;

        updateGradient();
    }

    /**
     * @param color the ending colour of the gradient
     */
    public void setEndColorResource(@ColorRes int color)
    {
        iEndColor = AppCompatUtils.getColor(getResources(), color);

        updateGradient();
    }

    /**
     * @param color the background colour of the progress ring
     */
    public void setBackgroundColor(@ColorInt int color)
    {
        iBackgroundColour = color;

        postInvalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @param color the background colour of the progress ring
     */
    public void setBackgroundColorResource(@ColorRes int color)
    {
        iBackgroundColour = AppCompatUtils.getColor(getResources(), color);

        postInvalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @param typeFace the typeface for the progress text
     */
    public void setTypeface(Typeface typeFace)
    {
        mTypeface = typeFace;

        mTextPaint.setTypeface(typeFace);

        postInvalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @param color the colour of the progress text
     */
    public void setTextColor(@ColorInt int color)
    {
        iTextColor = color;

        mTextPaint.setColor(iTextColor);

        postInvalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @param color the colour of the progress text
     */
    public void setTextColorResource(@ColorRes int color)
    {
        iTextColor = AppCompatUtils.getColor(getResources(), color);

        mTextPaint.setColor(iTextColor);

        postInvalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @param showProgress whether or not to show the progress as text in the middle of the progress ring
     */
    public void setShowProgress(boolean showProgress)
    {
        iShowProgress = showProgress;

        postInvalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @param showProgressPercentage show the progress as a percentage
     */
    public void setShowProgressPercentage(boolean showProgressPercentage)
    {
        iShowPercentage = showProgressPercentage;

        postInvalidate();
    }

    /**
     * The text to show in the middle of the progress ring. This is overridden if showProgress or
     * showProgressPercentage is set.
     *
     * @param text the text to show in the middle of the progress ring.
     */
    public void setText(String text)
    {
        iText = text;

        mTextLayout = null;

        postInvalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @param text additional text to show in a small font below the main text
     */
    public void setAdditionalText(String text)
    {
        iAdditionalText = text;

        mAddTextLayout = null;

        postInvalidate();
    }

    private void drawIndeterminate(@NonNull Canvas c)
    {
        if (iStart == -1)
            iStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

        period = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - iStart) % 10800) / 30;

        startAngle = period * 3;
        size = (float) Math.abs(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(period))) * 45 + 30;
        sweepAngle = size * 2;
        startAngle -= size;

        oldWidth = width;
        width = c.getWidth() > c.getHeight() ? c.getHeight() : c.getWidth();
        if (width != oldWidth || width == 0)
            resized();

        if (iBackgroundColour == Color.TRANSPARENT)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        else
            mPaint.setColor(iBackgroundColour);

        c.save();
        c.rotate(period * -1, width / 2, width / 2);

        if (iBackgroundColour != Color.TRANSPARENT)
            c.drawArc(new RectF(stroke, stroke, width - stroke, width - stroke), 0, 360, false, mPaint);
        mPaint.setShader(mGradient);
        c.drawArc(new RectF(stroke, stroke, width - stroke, width - stroke), startAngle, sweepAngle, false, mPaint);
        mPaint.setShader(null);
        c.restore();

        if (iAdditionalText != null)
        {
            int textSize = width / 12;

            mTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
            mTextPaint.setFakeBoldText(false);

            if (mAddTextLayout == null || resized)
                mAddTextLayout = new StaticLayout(iAdditionalText, mTextPaint, width, Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

            c.save();
            c.translate(0, (width - mAddTextLayout.getHeight()) / 2);
            mAddTextLayout.draw(c);
            c.restore();
        }

        resized = false;

        invalidate();
    }

    private void drawDeterminate(@NonNull Canvas c)
    {
        oldWidth = width;
        width = c.getWidth() > c.getHeight() ? c.getHeight() : c.getWidth();
        if (width != oldWidth)
            resized();

        angle = 360 * (getProgress() / (float) getMax()) * .98f;

        /* Draw background in blue for testing
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        c.drawRect(0,0,width,width,paint);
        //*/
        if (iBackgroundColour == Color.TRANSPARENT)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        else
            mPaint.setColor(iBackgroundColour);

        c.save();
        c.rotate(-90, width / 2, width / 2);

        if (iBackgroundColour != Color.TRANSPARENT)
            c.drawArc(new RectF(stroke, stroke, width - stroke, width - stroke), 0, 360, false, mPaint);
        mPaint.setShader(mGradient);
        c.drawArc(new RectF(stroke, stroke, width - stroke, width - stroke), 360 - angle, angle, false, mPaint);
        mPaint.setShader(null);

        c.restore();

        if (iShowPercentage && getMax() > 0)
        {
            iText = String.valueOf((getProgress() * 100) / getMax()) + "%";
        }
        else if (iShowProgress)
            iText = String.valueOf(getProgress());

        if (iText != null)
        {
            int textSize = width / 3;

            mTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
            mTextPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);

            if (mTextLayout == null || resized)
                mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(iText, mTextPaint, width, Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

            c.save();

            if (iAdditionalText == null)
                c.translate(0, (width - mTextLayout.getHeight()) / 2);
            else
            {
                int addSize = width / 12;
                c.translate(0, (width - (mTextLayout.getHeight() + addSize)) / 2);
            }
            mTextLayout.draw(c);


            if (iAdditionalText != null)
            {
                c.translate(0, textSize);

                textSize = width / 12;

                mTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
                mTextPaint.setFakeBoldText(false);

                if (mAddTextLayout == null || resized)
                    mAddTextLayout = new StaticLayout(iAdditionalText, mTextPaint, width, Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1f, 0f, false);
                mAddTextLayout.draw(c);
            }

            c.restore();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Change the indeterminate mode for this progress bar. In indeterminate
     * mode, the progress is ignored and the progress bar shows an infinite
     * animation instead.
     */
    @Override
    public void setIndeterminate(boolean indeterminate)
    {
        super.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);

        updateGradient();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas c)
    {
        if (isIndeterminate())
        {
            drawIndeterminate(c);
        }
        else
        {
            drawDeterminate(c);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        //Get the width measurement
        int widthSize = MeasureUtils.getMeasurement(widthMeasureSpec, 100000);

        //Get the height measurement
        int heightSize = MeasureUtils.getMeasurement(heightMeasureSpec, 100000);

        // Force square
        width = widthSize > heightSize ? heightSize : widthSize;

        //noinspection SuspiciousNameCombination
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);

        resized();
    }

    private void resized()
    {
        resized = true;
        stroke = width / 18;
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(stroke);
        updateGradient();
    }
}
```

attrs_progressbar_rounded_ring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ProgressBarRoundedRing">
        <attr name="colorStart" format="color"/>
        <attr name="colorEnd" format="color"/>
        <attr name="colorBackground" format="color"/>

        <attr name="colorText" format="color"/>
        <attr name="showProgress" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="showProgressAsPercentage" format="boolean"/>

        <!-- Text to show inside the ring. This is overriden if "showProgress" or "showProgressAsPercentage" is set to true -->
        <attr name="text" format="string"/>
        <attr name="additionalText" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

AppCompatUtils.java

```
package com.sss.utilities;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.ColorInt;
import android.support.annotation.ColorRes;
import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.Window;

/**
 * @author Tom Wijgers
 */
public class AppCompatUtils
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = AppCompatUtils.class.getName();

    public static @ColorInt int getColor(@NonNull Resources res, @ColorRes int color)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            //noinspection deprecation
            return res.getColor(color);
        }
        else
        {
            return res.getColor(color, null);
        }
    }

    public static @ColorInt int getColor(@NonNull Resources res, @ColorRes int color, @Nullable Resources.Theme theme)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            //noinspection deprecation
            return res.getColor(color);
        }
        else
        {
            return res.getColor(color, theme);
        }
    }

    public static Drawable getDrawable(@NonNull Resources res, @DrawableRes int drawable)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            //noinspection deprecation
            return res.getDrawable(drawable);
        }
        else
        {
            return res.getDrawable(drawable, null);
        }
    }

    public static Drawable getDrawable(@NonNull Resources res, @DrawableRes int drawable, @Nullable Resources.Theme theme)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            //noinspection deprecation
            return res.getDrawable(drawable);
        }
        else
        {
            return res.getDrawable(drawable, theme);
        }
    }

    public static void removeViewTreeObserver(@NonNull ViewTreeObserver obs, @NonNull ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        {
            obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
        }
        else
        {
            //noinspection deprecation
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
        }
    }

    public static void setStatusBarColor(@NonNull Window window, @ColorInt int color)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            window.setStatusBarColor(color);
        }
    }
}
```

TypefaceManager.java

```
package com.sss.utilities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author Tom Wijgers
 */
public class TypefaceManager
{
    private static final String TAG = TypefaceManager.class.getName();

    private static final Map<String, Typeface> sTypefaces = new HashMap<>();
    private static Context sContext = null;

    public static void init(Context c)
    {
        if(sContext == null)
            sContext = c;
    }

    public static Typeface getTypeface(String font)
    {
        Typeface tf = null;

        if(sTypefaces.containsKey(font))
            tf = sTypefaces.get(font);
        else if (sContext != null)
        {

            try
            {
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(sContext.getAssets(), font);
            }
            catch(RuntimeException rte)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, rte.getMessage(), rte);
            }


            if(tf != null)
                sTypefaces.put(font, tf);
        }

        return tf;
    }
}
```

MeasureUtils.java

```
package com.sss.utilities.widgets;

import android.view.View;

/**
 * @author Tom Wijgers
 */
class MeasureUtils
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = MeasureUtils.class.getName();

    public static int getMeasurement(int measureSpec, int contentSize) {
        int specMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
        int resultSize = 0;
        switch (specMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
                //Big as we want to be
                resultSize = contentSize;
                break;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                //Big as we want to be, up to the spec
                resultSize = Math.min(contentSize, specSize);
                break;
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                //Must be the spec size
                resultSize = specSize;
                break;
        }

        return resultSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom
Thanks for your quick response. but in your code you have imported these file. 

import com.sss.utilities.AppCompatUtils;
import com.sss.utilities.R;
import com.sss.utilities.TypefaceManager;

What are they?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added the two files. Simply change the .R import to your app's namespace. TypefaceManager is to help setting custom fonts in xml, and AppCompatUtils is to avoid deprecated APIs

Comment: MeasureUtils is also missing :(

Comment: Added for you now if you hadn't gotten it going yet.